# Delete Desktop contents for all the User Profiles

Tags: vbscript

Am new to vbscript and I have a task to delete all folders and files of all the user profiles under C:\Users am not an administrator but incharge of the vbscript for the team,I do not have administrator access to delete user profiles, multiple people would log in to the same desktop in all the shifts hence multiple user profiles will be created, the folder and files in desktop of all user profiles which are 30 days old should be deleted.

I have tried the below script found from different sources in google with the help of the Admin elevated privilegestried to run the script but still it is throwing permission denied for all user profiles folder.

```
On Error Resume Next
Dim objFSo, objFolder, objSubFolder, objFile,StrD,colSubFolders
Set objFSo = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set wshNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\")
Set colSubFolders = objFolder.SubFolders
For Each objSubFolder in colSubFolders
strD = objSubFolder
If (objFSo.FolderExists(objSubFolder)=True) Then
wshNetwork.Run "CMD /L TAKEOWN /F """ & strD & """ /R/D Y",1,True
For Each objFile In objFSo.GetFolder(strD).Files
If objFile.DateLastModified < (Now() - 30) Then
    objFSo.DeleteFile objFile.Path,True
End If
Next
```

The logic did not work and it throws Permission Denied 800A0046 in the second loop `For Each objFile In objFSo.GetFolder(strD).Files` which will not loop through any files under User Profile, could you please help me in the script which is the best way to delete Folders and files from desktop for all User profiles

Comment: Run the script with elevated permissions.

Comment: @Lankymart Thanks for your suggestion, I requested Admin access and tried to delete the files under User profiles using the above script but still the same Permission denied error in Windows 7 and Windows 10 is there any other way ?

Comment: your script is incomplete, it missed `end if` and `next` at the end. To ensure it works properly add `msgbox "strD=" & strD` and see what folder exactly it is not allowed to see.